# GDB stepping into shared library shows "no such file" even though debug symbols are loaded

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries

I have a C library which is created with

```sh
cc -fPIC -g -O3   -c -o obj/my_lib.o my_lib.c
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libmy_lib.so.1  obj/my_lib.o -o libmy_lib.so.1.8.0
```

This library is packaged into debian packages with `dpkg-buildpackage` producing `libmy_lib1-1.deb`, `libmy_lib1-dev-1.deb`, and `libmy_lib1-dbgsym-1.ddeb`. Installing all of those packages, I can then compile/link a simple test program that calls into the library. This works. Running the test program works.

However, when I run GDB on the test program (on the same computer), I see

```
gdb$ break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x87e: file test.c, line 10.
gdb$ info sharedlibrary
No shared libraries loaded at this time.
gdb$ r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:10
10        my_library_func();
gdb$ info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7dd5f10  0x00007ffff7df4b20  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7bac9a0  0x00007ffff7bad438  Yes         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmy_lib.so.1
0x00007ffff74532d0  0x00007ffff75cbc3c  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x00007ffff709fa80  0x00007ffff715e2f5  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x00007ffff6e7eac0  0x00007ffff6e8f36d  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
gdb$ s
my_library_func () at my_lib.c:299
299     my_lib.c: No such file or directory.
```

As you can see, GDB knows about the debug symbols for the library. However, it does not know about the source file for the library. How should I running GDB to it can resolve the C source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to also tell gdb where the source files are. Which means you also need the source files, not just the debugging symbols.

It's important that the sources you download are the actual ones used to compile the library, because debugging information only contains filename and line number. If you give gdb a file where the line numbers don't correspond (a different version, for example), the source lines printed by gdb will be very confusing. It has no way to know they are wrong. You should be able to use the src deb with the same version number as the library debs.

Once you have the source files, tell gdb where to look for them with

```
directory /path/to/source/files
```

You can specify several paths. Read `help directory` inside gdb.

Since you'll need to do this often, put that line into a [gdbinit](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gdbinit.5.html) file. You'll probably want to use `.gdbinit` in your current directory, but `.gdbinit` in your home directory might also be a possibility. Gdb uses both.

If you're working with a library whose source is spread over a subdirectory tree, you might find it useful to set a substitution path:

```
set substitute-path /your/file/path /original/file/path
```

Again, more help is available with `help set substitute-path`.

Comment: why do I need the actual source files for shared-libraries but not for standalone programs? I normally just install the debug-symbols along with the service I want to debug and it steps perfectly into the breakpoints. The first time I test this with shared-libraries it says it cannot find the source files, which is completely new to me? Can you explain this to me please?

Comment: @ElectRocnic: you do need the actual source files for standalone programs, too. The debugging information only contains the path to the source file. If you move or rename or delete the source file, then you'll get the same error message from gdb. That should be easy to test.

Comment: I actually searched for the files which `(gdb) info sources` lists, and could not find them on the filesystem with `find / -iname "*sourcefile.cpp*"`. But one service (standalone) can be debugged without any problems just by installing the debugging symbols debian package with `dpkg`. The other one is a jni application with a c++ shared library where I installed the debugging symbols and loaded it probably with gdb (as I verified with `(gdb) info sharedlibrary`, which lists my debugging symbols as loaded), but it fails when it hits the breakpoint stating `no such file or directory`.

Comment: @ElectRocnic: seems like you've done enough research to be able to easily construct a [mre] in a new question. I urge you to do that because it's very difficult to respond without specifics, and the specifics won't fit into a comment.

Comment: Ok my bad, thanks for the suggestion for the minimal example, I could therefore see that it is actually not even an issue if gdb does not find the source files, you can still hit and investigate variables during a breakpoint... My issue is therefore somewhere else. Not sure why I am not able to `printf "%s", stringVariable` during a breakpoint (getting `"Cannot convert to integer value"` error), but at least I excluded this as the reason. Thx!

Comment: Ok, turned out I was completely irritated by 4 (FOUR!) different error messages throughout the debugging session, and NONE of them are anyhow relevant. The most important thing was only that I must print a NON-EMPTY variable in the CORRECT WAY (e.g. `printf "%s", variable` did not work, but `print variable` did work perfectly fine at the end). The four errors which I can safely ignore are: 1. `gdb.error: No type named nmethod.` when gdb attaches to the jni application. 2. `hit breakpoint: ... source.cpp: No such file or directory.` (in my case not relevant),

Comment: 3. `Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> There is no member named _M_dataplus.: `, this does not do anything... and 4.: `Value can't be converted to integer.` actually was the best clue what my mistake was: I used the wrong print commands for either empty variables or for variables which did have a format where the command did not fit. Use the correct statements for the correct variable-type and you won't get this message.

thx for your help, it actually got me into the right direction!

Comment: I just have to add that some people may actually need the source files in their use-cases. My use-case is to hit a few breakpoints at a few specific line-numbers or function names, read the content of some variables at the breakpoint, and carry on (continue). No sources needed - just the debug symbols.

Comment: @elec: yes, the only effect of not having source files available is that you can't see the source. If you don't care about the source, you can ignore gdb's message; it's only trying to explain why it can't show you the line.

Comment: it should try harder, because at least for me this message seemed like an error and not like a warning.

Answer (score 1):

GDB searches a number of default directory paths to locate the specified sourcefile.  You can add paths using the `directory` command:  https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html